# Proving the transitivity of a relation

Tags: relations, problem-solving

I want to prove that the relation $\sim$ on fractions given by $\frac{a}{b} \sim \frac{c}{d}$ if $ad = cb$, where $a, c \in \mathbb Z$ and $b, d \in \mathbb Z_{> 0}$, is transitive.

(My last question was a similar sort of "is-this-a-valid-proof"-question; sorry if this is tiresome, but asking really, really turned out to help me, thanks to a very insightful user.)  So is this a valid proof (:-))?

Assume that $\frac{a}{b} \sim \frac{c}{d}$ and that $\frac{c}{d} \sim \frac{e}{f}$.  This means that $ad = cb$ and that $cf = de$.  We want to show that $af = be$ from the two previous equalities: $\textbf{af = be} \iff a = \frac{be}{f} \iff \frac{cb}{d} = \frac{be}{f} \iff \frac{c}{d} = \frac{e}{f} \iff \textbf{cf = de} \iff \frac{c}{d} = \frac{e}{f} \iff \frac{cb}{d} = \frac{be}{f} \iff \frac{ad}{d} = \frac{be}{f} \iff ad = b(\frac{de}{f}) \iff \textbf{ad = bc}.$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving this relation is transitive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77227/proving-this-relation-is-transitive)

Comment: @MarnixKlooster: Although the proposition involved is the same, the question does not seem to be.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this relation defined on pairs of integers $(a,b)$ when constructing the rational numbers from the integers. So, in this sense, maybe it's best to work only with properties of the integers (meaning not using fractions).

Supossing $a,c,e\neq 0$, since $ad=bc$ and $cf=de$ (and $b,d,f$ are already non-zero) we have

$acdf=bcde$

since we can cancel equal terms on both sides of the equation (making use of the cancellation law of the integers), we can cancel $cd$. Thus

$af=be$.

Comment: Well that is certainly much simpler and more concise!  Thanks for your great answer...however, is the proof I provided a valid one?

Comment: Oh, right, sorry: I see no logical error in your proof (assuming you can already use fractions). Although maybe you can shorten it by noting that the third equality ($\frac{cb}{d}=\frac{be}{f}$) is the same as the seventh equality.