# Equivalence Relations with equivalence classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Consider the following relation on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$: $(x, y)\sim (x', y')$ iff $xy' = x'y$.

**(a)** Prove that it is an equivalence relation.

**(b)** Consider the set of equivalence classes $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\sim$,  and denote the equivalence class of $(x,y)$ by $\overline{(x,y)}$. Define the following binary operations between equivalence classes:

1. $\overline{(x,y)} \cdot \overline{(x',y')} = \overline{(xx', yy')}$;
2. $\overline{(x,y)} + \overline{(x', y')} = (xy' + x'y, yy')$.

Prove that these operations are well defined, that is does not depend on a choice of a representative. Do you recognize the arithmetic system $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/ \sim$ you just constructed?

**My attempt:**

**(a)** Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.
Proof: We need to show that $\sim$ has the properties of reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.

1. Reflexivity: We need to show that $(x,y) \sim (x,y)$. Suppose $x' = x$ and $y' = y$, then $(x,y)\sim (x',y') \Rightarrow xy' = x'y \Rightarrow xy = xy \Rightarrow (x,y) \sim (x,y)$.
2. Symmetry: We need to show that $(x',y') \sim (x,y)$ given that $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$. Suppose $(x,y) \sim (x',y') \Rightarrow xy' = x'y \Rightarrow x'y = xy' \Rightarrow (x',y') \sim (x,y)$.
3. Transitivity: We need to show that $(x,y) \sim (x'',y'')$ given that $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ and $(x',y') \sim (x'',y'')$. Suppose $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ and $(x',y') \sim (x'',y'') \Rightarrow xy' = x'y$ and $x'y'' = x''y' \Rightarrow x' = xy'/y \Rightarrow xy'y''/y = x''y \Rightarrow xy'y'' = x''y'y \Rightarrow xy'' = x''y$. Therefore $(x,y) \sim (x'',y'')$.

**(b)** If I want to prove that something is well defined, generally I would use $x'$ and $y'$ and try to show that the representative doesn't matter. Would I do something like:

Since $\overline{(x,y)} \cdot \overline{(x',y')} = \overline{(xx',yy')}$, then $\overline{(x,y)} \cdot \overline{(x'',y'')} = \overline{(xx'',yy'')}$. If I rearrange both equations so that they equal $\overline{(x,y)}$ and then set both equations equal to each other, then I would get something like:

$\overline{(xx',yy')}/\overline{(x',y')} = \overline{(xx'',y'')}/\overline{(x'',y'')}$

and then multiply both sides by their denominator, I would get:

$\overline{(xx',yy')} \cdot \overline{(x'',y'')} = \overline{(x',y')} \cdot \overline{(xx'',y'')}$.

I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Think of $(x,y)$ as the rational number $\frac xy$, then you will get an idea of what you are doing and everything will fall in place.

Comment: So would the equivalence class for (x,y) for every element a in Z except for 0 such that x' = ax and y' = ay. Since the equivalent relation requires that xy' = x'y => x/y = x'/y' which just means that they're in a ratio with each other.

Comment: This question is about a very similar equivalence relation but on a different set: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297748/showing-that-r-is-an-equivalence-relation-on-x-times-x

Comment: And if it helps you can also have a look at a similar equivalence relation defined using addition instead of multiplication: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/equivalence-relation-a-b-r-c-d-leftrightarrow-a-d-b-c

Comment: And I should also mention that a more general construction is [field of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions).

Comment: BTW are you sure it is supposed to be $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ and not $\mathbb Z\times(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$? (This is what I would expect since you are asked: *Do you recognize the arithmetic system you just constructed?*)

Comment: Okay, so I have come to where (x,y) = x/y and (x',y') = x'/y' and when you multiply the two you get xx'/yy'. And if you do the same thing for the equivalence classes you get bar(x,y) * bar(x'y') = bar(xx'/yy'). I understand the intuition behind the statement now, but I don't know what I need to show in order to prove that it's well defined.