# Showing a relation in NxN is an equivalence relation, N denotes a set of positive integers

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $N∈Z^+$ and P represents a relation in$ N x N $defined by

$(a,b)P(c,d) $ iff $a + d = b + c$

we have to show that P is an equivalence relation

I tried to prove the reflexive property ,

then I'm confused whether to get $(a,a)   or   (a,b) $ ,

I can't find the head or tail of this question ,

can someone please explain clearly ,

Thank you so much !

Comment: The relation is on $N\times N$, so the reflexive property is that $(a,b)P(a,b)$. Can you show this?

Comment: What problems did you have with the remaining properties?

Comment: OK sir , thats fine  thank you so much

Comment: when proving for transitive property , do we have to get , (a,b)P(c,d) and (c,d)P(e,f)

Comment: You assume that and then aim to prove $(a,b)P(e,f)$. That proves the transitive property:
$$(a,b)P(c,d)\quad\text{and}\quad(c,d)P(e,f) \implies(a,b)P(e,f)$$

Comment: Thank you so much sir @PauloMourão

Comment: see similar thread https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21256/565609

Answer (score 2):

The reflexive property is $(a,b)P(a,b)$. Does that clear it up?

Answer

> This is equivalent to $a+b=a+b$ which is trivially true

Comment: Thank you so much